# degrees of freedom under system estimation

Tags: estimation, degrees-of-freedom

I'm trying to understand degrees of freedom where estimation involves simultaneous equations with cross-equation parameter restrictions.

I see an application with 21 data points and 5 parameters to estimate. A parameter which appears in the first equation can also appear in the third and so on. To me this appears to have a mere 21-5=16 dof!

But the authors says that since he’s estimating a system of 3 equations he’s actually using 3*21-5= 58 dof. Is this correct? Thanks!